# HereMAP Snapshot with Theme / Dark Mode

Tags: here-api, heremaps, heremaps-ios-sdk

How I can capture snapshot with DarkMode / Theme ?

I know current static/class method `snapshotWithGeoCoordinates:` which capture screen shot in default theme.

How I can apply theme and Capture?

Comment: Hi , What is your sdk version? Is it iOS SDK 3.18 Premium?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use iOS SDK 3.18 Premium.

It is only possible to make snapshot with style that currently map view uses. To achieve your requirement, you need to set NMAMapSchemeNormalNight scheme for the NMAMapVIew and then make snapshot. More detials about the map schema, please refer to https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/3.18/dev_guide/topics/map-schemes.html